# How place the components the front of another one?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I want to place the components A and B over component with List. I need that would text of list will be to visible. I can not find which layout can do it.
How this behavior is in lwuit? What solutions exist?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, jmunoz answer is correct if you want component's A and B to reside at the bottom of the screen and the list to scroll above. However from the drawing it seems you want an "always on top" effect which you can achieve either via a glass pane (for non-interactive components) or via the `LayeredLayout` class.

This is actually quite simple using the following:

```
myForm.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
myForm.setScrollable(false);

// will occupy the entire area of the form but should be scrollable
myForm.addComponent(componentUnderneath);
Container south = new Container(new BorderLayout());
myForm.addComponent(south);
south.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, whateverYouWantToPlaceOnTopInTheSouth);
```

Comment: Personally I think the LayerdLayout class will achieve what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You must do the following:

The `Form` must not do scroll. Use `Form.setScrollable(false)`. Set the layout of the ´Form´ to `BORDER_LAYOUT`, `myForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout())` . Ok in `BorderLayout`you can put the  components in the `Form` as you want.

Put the `List`component in the center of the `BorderLayout` with `myForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, List)` and the other two elements in the south of the layout using

```
Container southContainer = new Container();
southContainer.addComponent(A);
southContainer.addComponent(B);
myForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southContainer)
```

With this you can get a scrollable `List`and two elements always visible.